# How to send Serial data to a UDP switch?

Tags: windows, networking, udp, serial

I have a data string I am receiving via a serial port to my computer.  I would like to be able to send this data back out over UDP or TCP to a switch to be received by a remote sensor.

Networking is not my forte, any advice out there?

Comment: I am using Windows.

Comment: I guess in Linux `socat` is able to do it. I don't know Windows tools but maybe this information will advance your own research.

Comment: Does the sensor already require the data to be sent over a specific protocol, or are you just building everything as you go?

Comment: The sensor can receive any signal, my problem is that in order to use a serial protocol I would need to create a new connector, waterproof it and interface it.  (the signal will be sent via a fibreoptic connection subsea).It already has a network cable attached which can handle multiple UDP inputs, I think it could even receive TCP, but its quite time critical, so waiting for replies might impair its function.